# NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays from NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a number of objects in NSArray. I want to reconstract NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays with 6 elements in each out of NSArray. How can I do it?

**Edit**
My code:

```
NSArray *newsList = [mynode6 findChildTags:@"td"]; //result of site parsing
NSMutableArray *someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i=0;
for (HTMLNode *news in newsList) { 
    [someArray addObject:[newsList objectAtIndex:news];
    i++;
    if (i==5) {
        i=0;
        [self.valueArray addObject:someArray];
        [someArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

`valueArray` is my main NSMutableArray. This code does not work, `valueArray` is empty.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you have vs. what you would like to have? It does not look like the mapping you're trying to achieve is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix:

Allocate the array within your loop:

```
NSArray *newsList = [mynode6 findChildTags:@"td"]; //result of site parsing
NSMutableArray *someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int i=0;
for (HTMLNode *news in newsList) { 
    [someArray addObject:[newsList objectAtIndex:news];

    if (++i == 5) {
        i = 0;
        [self.valueArray addObject:someArray];
        [someArray release];
        someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

[someArray release];
```

Comment: I have error with your code `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 120 beyond bounds [0 .. 119]'`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your approach is too obtuse for your average programmer...but alas...

Do you really want to reuse `someArray` in the manner you have listed above?  Adding `someArray` as an object of `valueArray` and then removing all objects later will just leave your `valueArray` full of empty arrays.  Worse, you are adding the same array instance every single time...

Maybe instead of `[someArray removeAllObjects]` you just make a new instance `someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`

Then after your for loop, make sure to add whatever is left over in `someArray`:

```
if(i) {
    [self.valueArray addObject:someArray];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with empty arrays after doing something similar. At the point you add the array in make it look like this..

```
[self.valueArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:someArray]];
```

This worked for me! Its because you add a reference to someArray then remove all the objects hence its empty. By additing it arrayWithArray you make a copy of the data so removing the rows form one leaves them in the other. :)

Plasma

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand this line.This line is not meaningful as  objectAtIndex takes NSInteger as param..I presume ur trying to add HTMLNode element in that array

```
[someArray addObject:[newsList objectAtIndex:news];
```

So,I think u need to replace the above line like this..

```
[someArray addObject:news];
```

I have edited ur code snippet by making a few changes and i have plugged in my logic(Have created a new newsList array with some dummy objects to explain u the logic)..

Here goes the edited code

```
NSArray *newsList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F", nil];
    NSMutableArray *valueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int i=0;
    for (NSString *news in newsList) { 
    [someArray addObject:news];
     i++;
     if (i==6) {
         i=0;
         [valueArray addObject:someArray];
         NSLog(@"%@",someArray);
         [someArray release];
         someArray = [NSMutableArray new]; 
     }
     }

NSLog(@"%@",valueArray);
```

Here is the output from terminal..
[image]

Hope it helped!! Have a good reading!